# Pandas if row name is not a specific string change to desired string name

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a pandas dataframe.  I would like to change the name in a column if it DOES NOT equal "false" to the word "NAMED".

```
df
   hash
0  false
1  false
2  asldkjfl645sd54
3  false
4  65s4d65a3s21d12
5  2s1d53a54d5f1a3
```

Desired output:

```
df
   hash
0  false
1  false
2  NAMED
3  false
4  NAMED
5  NAMED
```

Comment: `df['hash'].where(df['hash'].eq('false'), 'NAMED')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'hash':['false','false','asldkjfl645sd54','34ds','65s4d65a3s21d12','2s1d53a54d5f1a3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df['hash'] = df['hash'].where(df['hash'] == 'false', 'NAMED')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    hash
0  false
1  false
2  NAMED
3  NAMED
4  false
5  NAMED
```